# Gcode to tell a RepRap 3D printer he is in the middle of the heat bed?

Tags: g-code

Is there a way to tell a RepRap 3D printer that he is in the middle of a heatbed using a specific gcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the coordinates to start at center (once you are already there) via G91:

G91: Set to Relative Positioning

Example: G91

All coordinates from now on are relative to the last position

from http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M117:_Get_Zero_Position